# Python: Is there any way to get the n-th order antiderivative of a periodic 3D signal/field without padding data?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, spline

As stated in the title, I want to obtain the n-th (e.g. 4-th) order antiderivative of a 3D field (e.g. array with shape (1024,1024,1024) ) with period L on each side. **If I need the antiderivative values beyond period L, I have to pad the data periodically ("wrap") before solving the antiderivative.** However, this approach is highly memory consumption, particularly for the 1024^3 array. My Python code snippet is shown below:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline
data = np.load("xxx.npy") # shape: (1024,1024,1024)
data_pad = np.pad(data, ( (1024,1024), (1024,1024), (1024,1024) ), "wrap")

# 4th antiderivative of the padded data along x
interp_x = make_interp_spline(x_pad, data_pad, k=3, axis=0)
interp_x4 = interp_x.antiderivative(4)
```

Is there other way to achieve the same goal without padding data?

Comment: does `bc_type='periodic'` fix it?

Comment: @LudvigH Where to use ```bc_type='periodic'```?

Comment: @LudvigH I tried, but it doesn't help.

Comment: A quick comment is that of course you are creating a new `interp_x4 ` object instead of calling the old one `interp(..., nu=-4) `

Comment: @ev-br Can you be more clear?

Comment: The use of `np.load()` makes your example opaque to others. Can you synthesize some input data instead?

Comment: Your data is in a regular grid? If so, why don't you simply use the Fourier representation of it?

Comment: @Bob the Fourier representation does not need a regular grid (although the implementation would be much slower). Anyway I think it would be the best approach in this case, but extra care must be taken for odd-order derivatives when it comes to the definition domain, since FT is an inherent C² -> C² transformation, and multiplying by `iξ` the function `F(ξ)` FT-transform of `f(x)` mixes real and imaginary parts of `F(ξ)` so that the derivative of `f(x)` is not necessarily purely real any longer.

Comment: @Bob Yes my data is in a regular grid

Comment: What would `x_pad` be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments for periodic signals you can get antiderivatives from the Fourier transfrom.

If your function is `(n+1)` times differentiable, you can get `n` derivatives, after that you will have problems related to the [Gibbs phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon)

It is sad that we don't have equations support here

but using the [translation identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Translation_/_time_shifting) you can get e.g. `(f(x+a) - f(x-a)) / (2*a)`, as `D(omega) * F(omega)`, and if `D(omega)` is non-zero everywhere, you can invert the derivation.

Let's start with a 1D example

```
import numpy as np

y = np.linspace(-4, 4, 256)
Y = np.fft.fft(y)
dt = np.exp(-np.fft.fftfreq(len(Y)) * 2j * np.pi)
dyOp = (dt**-0.5 - dt**0.5) * len(y) / (4 - (-4))
y_derivative = np.fft.ifft(dyOp * Y).real 
y_a1 = np.fft.ifft(np.divide(Y, dyOp, where=dyOp!=0)).real
y_a2 = np.fft.ifft(np.divide(Y, dyOp**2, where=dyOp!=0)).real
y_a3 = np.fft.ifft(np.divide(Y, dyOp**3, where=dyOp!=0)).real

plt.plot(y, y)
plt.plot(y, y_a1)
plt.plot(y, y_a2)
plt.plot(y, y_a3)
plt.ylim([-8, 8])
plt.legend(['y=t/4', '$d^{-1}ydt$', '$d^{-2}y dt^2$', '$d^{-3}y dt^3$'], ncol=2)
```

If your data has multiple dimensions you can apply this for for each axis individually

Assuming that your dimensions are `0 <= x,y,z < 1` with period 1

then you could write

```
period_x = 1
period_y = 1
period_z = 1

# used 1j pi, to avoid taking the square root down there
dx = np.exp(- 1j * np.pi * np.fft.fftfreq(data.shape[0])).reshape(-1, 1, 1)
dy = np.exp(- 1j * np.pi * np.fft.fftfreq(data.shape[1])).reshape(1, -1, 1)
dz = np.exp(- 1j * np.pi * np.fft.fftfreq(data.shape[2])).reshape(1, 1, -1)

data_dx = (dx.conj() - dx) * data.shape[0] / period_x
data_dy = (dx.conj() - dx) * data.shape[1] / period_y
data_dz = (dx.conj() - dx) * data.shape[2] / period_z

# maybe you will want to set some tolerance arround zero
data_dx[data_dx == 0] = 1
data_dy[data_dy == 0] = 1
data_dz[data_dz == 0] = 1
```

Suppose you want to solve the [Poison's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%27s_equation), you can do it by

```
D = np.fft.nfftn(data)
divergent_op = (data_dx**2 + data_dy**2 + data_dz**2)
data_divergent = np.fft.ifftn(D / divergent_op).real
```